The situation makes it impossible for you to stay
”The situation makes it impossible for you to stay”
In this sentence, what does “It” refer to? Does “it” act as a placeholder for “to stay”?
I think 'it' is not a dummy subject, maybe it could be anticipatory.
If you think 'it' is a dummy subject, prove it.

Here at ELL, it is expected that one search existing questions (and answers) before posting a new question. If one finds a similar question but the answer doesn’t quite resolve one’s own question, then one should point that out and explain how one’s own question is different and the existing answers fall short.
